# Keep scrollback after clear

Tags: terminal, tmux

Basically, the functionality I want to achieve is that I can type `clear` or press Ctrl-L and have the terminal screen be cleared, but have the contents remain in the tmux scrollback buffer.

Right now (tmux 2.9a on Arch), issuing a clear causes everything in the scrollback, except exactly one screen height worth of lines, to be discarded. However, on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine I found an old tmux 2.6 version that I built from source, which behaves as I want it to.

Other than the difference in version and distro, the former uses Powerline 2.7 while the latter uses Powerline 2.6. Not sure if that could make a difference.

Is this just a feature/bug (?) from an old tmux version that got removed/fixed, or is there some way to get that functionality back on my current machine?

Comment: Newer versions of `clear` clear everything including the scrollback. Use `clear -x` to keep the scrollback. Also, ncurses patch 20180804 made a relevant change: prior to this change you could end up with one screen of data in the scrollback, while after this change this should no longer happen: it's either preserved or completely wiped out. Yet another relevant thing: xterm clears the onscreen contents (the last screenful of your output) while tmux seems to scroll it out to the scrollback.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I've now aliased `clear` to `clear -x` and it works as I want it to again.

Comment: related: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Moving.html